# How to change the resolution after booting Arch Linux installation medium?

Tags: arch-linux, tty, resolution

Is it possible to change the screen resolution after fully booting the Arch Linux installation medium? I tried to [add `vga=795` to the boot line](http://go2linux.garron.me/change-boot-up-resolution-console-text-mode/), and that worked for a few lines before the resolution was changed back to an unreadable 4K. And the [various](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_mode_setting#My_fonts_are_too_tiny) [suggestions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Linux_console) in the wiki seem to assume that I have already set up networking and can install packages.

With the help of a [guide to the default console fonts](https://alexandre.deverteuil.net/pages/consolefonts/) I was able to set the largest available using `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/iso01-12x22.psfu.gz`, but that is still barely readable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In addition to changing the font size to a larger one, with `setfont`, you can also pass kernel parameters on the boot loader line. The ISO uses [Syslinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux), so you can hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> when the menu appears and append these parameters to the [kernel line](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#Syslinux). Two that would be most useful are:

- `nomodeset` to [disable KMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KMS)
- `video=1024x768` to force a specific resolution if KMS is required.

Comment: Great answer. But with systemd-boot, I think `e` is the key to press not Tab.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist Correct: you can just edit that sort of thing into the answer.

Comment: video=1024x768 (or in my case 1920x1080, 1/4 actual resolution) worked great.

Answer (score 8):

How to install and use a reasonable font:

1. Set up networking using a handy microscope
2. `pacman --sync --refresh terminus-font`
3. `setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/ter-132n.psf.gz` (UEFI mode) or `setfont /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/ter-132n.psf.gz` (CSM mode)

Comment: I found that fon't didn't exist on the version of Arch I downloaded today. latarcyrheb-sun32.psfu.gz worked just as well.

Comment: It looks like the fonts directory has moved to /usr/share/kbd/consolefonts/.

Comment: @Fopedush No, all the .psf.gz files are still in `/usr/share/kbd/consolefonts`